# How can I prevent mapstruct from mapping lots of fields without having to exclude them all manually?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dto, mapstruct

I'm using mapstruct to map an object to a DTO. My object has 100 fields that need to be mapped in the DTO, and about 30 that shouldn't be mapped.

How can I ignore the 30 fields without having to write 30 times

```
@Mapping(source = "fieldtoIgnore", ignore = true)
```

I'm not looking to ignore the warning, I want to completely prevent mapstruct from mapping some fields

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can define on the mapping method the following annotation:

```
@BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true)
```

this will make mapstruct to ignore by default all matching fields between the two classes.

Here is a Quotation from Mapstruct documentation regarding this annotation:

> By means of the @BeanMapping(ignoreByDefault = true) the default
>   behavior will be explicit mapping, meaning that all mappings have to
>   be specified by means of the @Mapping and no warnings will be issued
>   on missing target properties.

and link to the javadoc:
http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/api/org/mapstruct/BeanMapping.html

Comment: I should've precised that I'm using mapstruct 1.2, so this won't work. Thank you